# Style display:none not working in IE8, IE9, IE10 Compatibility View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two DIVs on my page. One of them is set to **display:none** based on some condition. It works well on IE10, Firefox and Chrome. But it does not work on IE8, IE9 and IE10 Compatibility View. As a result, it shows both of the DIVs. Can someone suggest what to do to fix this issue?

```
<div id="dv1" style="background: url(http://abc.com/images/green.gif) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent; height: 26px; width: 171px; display: none;"></div>


<div id="dv2" style="background:url(http://abc.com/images/red.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;height:26px; width:142px; padding-left:18px;padding-right:11px;"/>
```

Comment: I have update the code by providing closing div tags. Please have a look.

Comment: You should learn basic HTML first. First you didn't close the `div` tag, and after the edit you closed it like `img` tag? This is not the way you close a `div` tag.

Comment: `div`s are not self-closing, please use  literal `</div>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put `</div>` for both divs.

I think you want something like below.

```
<div id="dv1" style="background: url(http://abc.com/images/green.gif) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent; height: 26px; width: 171px; display: none;"></div>

<div id="dv2" style="background:url(http://abc.com/images/red.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;height:26px; width:142px; padding-left:18px;padding-right:11px;"></div>
```

Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JSHn7/), it works fine in all browsers.

Comment: It's working fine for me in Firefox, Chrome, IE10,9 and 8. Try it.

Comment: Use the link which I gave you, test it in all browsers, it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

`<div>` is **not a self closing tag**. You cannot end this tag by writing it as `<div .... />` at the end. They are container tag and they **should contain some element** for `display: none` to work.

For example:

```
<div style="display: none;">
     What ever inside will never show
</div>
```

Make these changes and it will work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide both DIVs, your html markup should be like that, `div2` must be inside `div1`

```
<div id="dv1" style="background: url(http://abc.com/images/green.gif) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent; height: 26px; width: 171px; display: none;">
    <!-- div1 content -->    
    <div id="dv2" style="background:url(http://abc.com/images/red.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;height:26px; width:142px; padding-left:18px;padding-right:11px;">
        <!-- div2 content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS instead of inline styling

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     .dv1 {
       background: url(http://abc.com/images/green.gif) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent; 
       height: 26px; 
       width: 171px; 
       display: none;
     }
     .dv2 {
       background:url(http://abc.com/images/red.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
       height:26px; 
       width:142px; 
       padding-left:18px;
       padding-right:11px;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="dv1"></div>
    <div id="dv2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```